# Relacionamento Unilateral EF sql Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

Estou com problema no relacionamento de entidades com o Entity Framework Core `v3.1.5`, `Code First`

Tenho entidade `Cliente` que relaciona com a entidade `DadosProfissional` e o meu problema é, quando cadastro um cliente, mesmo não tendo informações para dados profissional, é feito `Insert` nessa tabela e gostaria que isso acontecesse somente quando realmente tivesse informação para essa entidade.

A classe esta cliente:

```
public class Cliente
{
    public Int64 ClienteId { get; set; }
    public String Nome { get; set; }        
    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
    public String Telefone { get; set; }
    public string Filhos { get; set; }
    public Int64? PaisId { get; set; }
    public virtual Pais Pais { get; set; }
    public Int64? EstadoId { get; set; }
    public virtual Estado Estado { get; set; }
    public Int64? CidadeId { get; set; }
    public Int64? DadosProfissionalId { get; set; }
    public virtual DadosProfissional DadosProfissional { get; set; }
    public virtual Cidade Cidade { get; set; }
    public string RG { get; set; }
    public string CPF { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class DadosProfissional
{
    public Int64 DadosProfissionailId { get; set; }
    public Int64? ProfissaoId { get; set; }
    public Int64? NivelId { get; set; }
    public Int64? EmpresaId { get; set;}
    public Int64? PaisId { get; set; }
    public Int64? EstadoId { get; set; }
    public Int64? CidadeId { get; set; }
    public int? SituacaoContratoId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataInicio { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataFim { get; set; }
    public decimal? Renda { get; set; }
    public virtual Pais Pais { get; set; }
    public virtual Estado Estado { get; set; }
    public virtual Cidade Cidade { get; set; }
    public virtual Profissao Profissao { get; set; }
    public virtual Nivel Nivel { get; set; }
    public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }
    public virtual SituacaoContrato SituacaoContrato { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: se `DadosProfissional` estiver null ele não vai inserir

Comment: era exatamente esse comportamento que eu esperava... mas está inserindo

Comment: se o objeto está null, como pode inserir algum valor? o EF não pode "inventar" dados, ele só insere o que há nos objetos, verifique novamente a property, tem algo errado. Outra possibilidade é "desatachar" o tabela `DadosProfissional` do modelo ao salvar, algo como `objetoDeContext.Entry(DadosProfissional).State = EntityState.Detached`

Comment: o que pode esta acontecendo é que o auto-mapper, cria um novo objeto, qndo faço o mapeamento e por isso ele faz o insert

Comment: A estratégia é outra, precisa criar nessa Entidade ou até melhor em outra Classe que representa esse modelo uma validação onde é obrigado que todos os campos inclusive da relação sejam preenchidos.